# The filter function does not remove the object in the array in Vue/Vuex

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuex

I am busy with making a booking function in vue3/vuex.
A user can book an item and also remove it from the basket.The problem is that the Filter function in vue does not remove the object in the array and I can not find out what the problem is. I hope you can help me

This is the result if I put `console.log()` in the `removeFromBasket(state, payload)`

```
removeFromBasket(state, payload) {
        console.log('removeFromBasket', payload, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.basket.items)))
    }
```

[image]

- method to remove

```
removeFromBasket() {
      this.$store.commit('basket/removeFromBasket', this.bookableId);
}
```

- basket module

```
const state = {
    basket: {
        items: []
    },
};

const getters = {
    getCountOfItemsInBasket: (state) => {
        return state.basket.items.length
    },
    getAllItemsInBasket: (state) => {
        return state.basket.items
    },
    inBasketAlready(state) {
        return function (id) {
            return state.basket.items.reduce((result, item) => result || item.bookable.id === id, false);
        }
    },   
};

const actions = {};

const mutations = {
    addToBasket(state, payload) {
        state.basket.items.push(payload);
    },
    removeFromBasket(state, payload) {
        state.basket.items = state.basket.items.filter(item => item.bookable.id !== payload);
    }
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put a `console.log('removeFromBasket', payload, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.basket.items)))` inside your `removeFromBasket` mutation to see what the data is?

Comment: I don't see `items` in `basket`.

Comment: How do you verify that it does not work? I checked your code in a playground and it seems to work. Can you provide a bit more of the code, as the problem seems to be somewhere else? For example, check if the payload is actually what you need or if the mutation is called at all, if it is possible, show us the bookable object istelf and the already pushed data.

Comment: @Duannx I have put the result in my code above

Comment: @Amini I have add the new image

Comment: @Zarok the mutation gets called and I have put it in the console.log as you can see above. I don't know why it does not work. what funny to me is if I use--->  tate.basket.items = state.basket.items.filter(item => item.bookable.id === payload); instead of--->  state.basket.items = state.basket.items.filter(item => item.bookable.id !== payload); it works! but it is not the soloution! right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
I used `typeof()` in `console.log()` to see what type the `payload` and `item.bookable.id` are.
The `payload` was a string and the `item.bookable.id` was a number.
So I put the `payload` in `parseInt(payload)` and the problem was solved.

```
removeFromBasket(state, payload) {
   state.basket.items = state.basket.items.filter(item => item.bookable.id !== parseInt(payload));
}
```